# Python: Iterating through a list and returning a tuple permutation for all strings in the list?

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have a list of elements: list = ['A','B',C']. How do I iterate through this list and return the following: [AB, AC, BC]?

note: I only want unique pairs, not [AA, BB, CC...] or [AB, BA, BC, CB...]

Comment: Or [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170248/6045800) from another question covering basically all options to combine the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
In [1]: from itertools import combinations

In [2]: for c in combinations(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2):
   ...:     print(c)
   ...: 
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'C')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using the permutations module initially and it eventually ran into an error!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way

```
lst = ['A','B','C']
result=[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
        result.append(lst[i]+lst[j])
```